# Python: Intersection of spheres

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

I am extremely new to programming but I decided to take on an interesting project as I recently learnt how to represent a sphere in parametric form. When intersecting three spheres, there are two points of intersections that are distinct unless they only overlap at a singular point.

Parametric representation of a sphere:

[image]

The code I have is modified from the answer from [Python/matplotlib : plotting a 3d cube, a sphere and a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/python-matplotlib-plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector), adding the ability to dictate the x, y and z origin and the radius of the sphere. Many similar questions were written in C++, Java, and C#, which I cannot understand at all (I barely know what I am doing so go easy on me).

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np

def make_sphere_x(x, radius):
  u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:5000j, 0:np.pi:2500j]
  x += radius * np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
  return x

def make_sphere_y(y, radius):
  u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:5000j, 0:np.pi:2500j]
  y += radius * np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
  return y

def make_sphere_z(z, radius):
  u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:5000j, 0:np.pi:2500j]
  z += radius * np.cos(v)
  return z

#x values
sphere_1_x = make_sphere_x(0, 2)
sphere_2_x = make_sphere_x(1, 3)
sphere_3_x = make_sphere_x(-1, 4)
#y values
sphere_1_y = make_sphere_y(0, 2)
sphere_2_y = make_sphere_y(1, 3)
sphere_3_y = make_sphere_y(0, 4)
#z values
sphere_1_z = make_sphere_z(0, 2)
sphere_2_z = make_sphere_z(1, 3)
sphere_3_z = make_sphere_z(-2, 4)

#intercept of x-values
intercept_x = list(filter(lambda x: x in sphere_1_x, sphere_2_x))
intercept_x = list(filter(lambda x: x in intercept_x, sphere_3_x))
print(intercept_x)
```

**Problems:**

1. Clearly there must be a better way of finding the intercepts. Right now, the code generates points at equal intervals, with the number of intervals I specify under the imaginary number in `np.mgrid`. If this is increased, the chances of an intersection should increase (I think) but when I try to increase it to `10000j` or above, it just spits a memory error.
2. There are obvious gaps in the array and this method would most likely be erroneous even if I have access to a super computer and can crank up the value to an obscene value. Right now the code results in a null set.
3. The code is extremely inefficient, not that this is a priority but people like things in threes right?

Feel free to flame me for rookie mistakes in coding or asking questions on Stack Overflow. Your help is greatly valued.

Comment: In general, this problem cannot be solved by sampling points - precisely because of the discretization (and also because of numerical inaccuracy).

Comment: My advice is to first work on a simpler problem, namely the intersection of two circles.

Comment: The intersection of two spheres is a circle. (This can be determined easily. EDIT: if both spheres have the same radius.) Now all you need to do is find the intersection of the third sphere and the aforementioned circle. (This can be determined easily. EDIT: if all spheres have the same radius.)

Comment: Actually, I think the problem becomes easier if you make use of rotations. (a la conjugation R T R^-1) Then I think my suggestion generalizes to arbitrary radiuses more easily.

Comment: Adding the link to this question as a related but slightly different problem. You may find some inspiration in it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406375/finding-intersection-points-between-3-spheres

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding intersection points between 3 spheres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406375/finding-intersection-points-between-3-spheres)

Answer (score 3):

Using `scipy.optimize.fsolve` you can find the root of a given function, given an initial guess that is somewhere in the range of your solution. I used this approach to solve your problem and it seems to work for me. The only downside is that it only provides you one intersection. To find the second one you would have to tinker with the initial conditions until `fsolve` finds the second root.

First we define our spheres by defining (arbitrary) radii and centers for each sphere:

```
a1 = np.array([0,0,0])
r1 = .4
a2 = np.array([.3,0,0])
r2 = .5
a3 = np.array([0,.3,0])
r3 = .5
```

We then define how to transform back into cartesian coordinates, given angles `u,v`

```
def position(a,r,u,v):
    return a + r*np.array([np.cos(u)*np.sin(v),np.sin(u)*np.sin(v),np.cos(v)])
```

Now we think about what equation we need to find the root of. For any intersection point, it holds that for perfect `u1,v1,u2,v2,u3,v3` the positions `position(a1,r1,u1,v1) = position(a2,r2,u2,v2) = position(a3,r3,u3,v3)` are equal. We thus find three equations which must be zeros, namely the differences of two position vectors. In fact, as every vector has 3 components, we have 9 equations which is more than enough to determine our 6 variables.

We find the function to minimize as:

```
def f(args):
    u1,v1,u2,v2,u3,v3,_,_,_ = args
    pos1 = position(a1,r1,u1,v1)
    pos2 = position(a2,r2,u2,v2)
    pos3 = position(a3,r3,u3,v3)
    return np.array([pos1 - pos2, pos1 - pos3, pos2 - pos3]).flatten()
```

`fsolve` needs the same amount of input and output arguments. As we have 9 equations but only 6 variables I simply used 3 dummy variables so the dimensions match. Flattening the array in the last line is necessary as `fsolve` only accepts 1D-Arrays.

Now the intersection can be found using fsolve and a (pretty random) guess:

```
guess = np.array([np.pi/4,np.pi/4,np.pi/4,np.pi/4,np.pi/4,np.pi/4,0,0,0])

x0 = fsolve(f,guess)
u1,v1,u2,v2,u3,v3,_,_,_ = x0
```

You can check that the result is correct by plugging the angles you received into the `position` function.

Comment: +1 What would this look like for an intersection of four spheres? I think not much different, however I'm not sure.

Comment: @KeithMadison The code should look the same for four spheres, just add an additional position 'pos4' in the definition of f and three additional equations 'pos1 - pos4', 'pos2 - pos4', 'pos3 - pos4'. However, unlike with three spheres, I am not sure if there is a rule telling us whether a solution actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be better tackled using trigonometry.

Reducing the problem into 2D circles, we could do:

```
import math
import numpy

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, cx, cy, r):
        """initialise Circle and set main properties"""
        self.centre = numpy.array([cx, cy])
        self.radius = r

    def find_intercept(self, c2):
        """find the intercepts between the current Circle and a second c2"""
        #Find the distance between the circles
        s = c2.centre - self.centre
        self.dx, self.dy = s
        self.d = math.sqrt(numpy.sum(s**2))
        #Test if there is an overlap.  Note: this won't detect if one circle completly surrounds the other.
        if self.d > (self.radius + c2.radius):
            print("no interaction")
        else:
            #trigonometry
            self.theta = math.atan2(self.dy,self.dx)
            #cosine rule
            self.cosA = (c2.radius**2 - self.radius**2 + self.d**2)/(2*c2.radius*self.d)
            self.A = math.acos(self.cosA)

            self.Ia = c2.centre - [math.cos(self.A+self.theta)*c2.radius, math.sin(self.A+self.theta)*c2.radius]
            self.Ib = c2.centre - [math.cos(self.A-self.theta)*c2.radius,-math.sin(self.A-self.theta)*c2.radius]

            print("Interaction points are : ", self.Ia, " and: ", self.Ib)


#define two arbitrary circles 
c1 = Circle(2,5,5)
c2 = Circle(1,6,4)


#find the intercepts
c1.find_intercept(c2)

#test results by reversing the operation
c2.find_intercept(c1)
```