# How to find coordinate of a point at a specific distance from three other points?

Tags: python, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xipYs.jpg)**Coordinates of three points are (-2.5466649, -1.2534076, 0.0001741), (-2.6229969, 1.6419994, 0.0000651) and (-2.6972299, 2.8495214, 0.0003421). Would like to find a point at distance of 1.01, 3.91 and 5.12, respectively.**

```
import numpy as np
x1=-2.5466649
y1=-1.2534076
z1= 0.0001741
x2=-2.6229969
y2= 1.6419994
z2= 0.0000651
x3=-2.6972299
y3= 2.8495214
z3= 0.0003421
#distance
l1=1.01
l2=3.91
l3=5.12
#coefficient 
a1=2*(x2-x1)
a2=2*(x3-x2)
a3=2*(x1-x3)
b1=2*(y2-y1)
b2=2*(y3-y2)
b3=2*(y1-y3)
c1=2*(z2-z1)
c2=2*(z3-z2)
c3=2*(z1-z3)
d1 = l1**2 - l2**2 - x1**2 - y1**2 - z1**2 + x2**2 + y2**2 + z2**2
d2 = l2**2 - l3**2 - x2**2 - y2**2 - z2**2 + x3**2 + y3**2 + z3**2
d3 = l3**2 - l1**2 - x3**2 - y3**2 - z3**2 + x1**2 + y1**2 + z1**2
a = np.array([[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]])
b = np.array([d1, d2, d3])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print x # [-5.00886518e+02 -1.78735572e+01 -6.55360000e+04]
```

Comment: there are infinite results of coordinates for each distance. This distances are setup for each point? Can You post a graphic representation of what you try to archive?

Comment: yes you are right, there will be infinite coordinates for each distance just like a sphere. But I would like to find the intersecting point of three sphere. There will be only one point. Thanks!

Comment: then you try to find sphere based on this coordinates?

Comment: Actually, there will be no intersection. Compute, for example the distance between the first two points. I'm getting 2.896.. for that. As the point you are looking for is 1.01 from point 1 it can by triangle inequality be no more than 3.906.. from point 2.

Comment: @ Zaraki Kenpachi, I have added a graphical representation of the problem.

Comment: @ Paul, yes you are right. I have rounded down to two decimal places which becomes 3.91. I am not sure this could be problem or not. Also, I would like to let you know that all the points almost on the straight line.

Comment: Well, the two together are certainly toxic. Just have a look at the condition number of your matrix (`np.linalg.cond(a)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think from your graphical depiction, you are referring to trilateration. More info on that [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrilaterationAndTheIntersectionOfThreeSpheres/)

Also I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406375/8824174) which has some code in one of its answers ([link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18654302/8824174)) given by Andrew.
Sharing the same code here for your question.

```
import numpy                                             
from numpy import sqrt, dot, cross                       
from numpy.linalg import norm
# Find the intersection of three spheres                 
# P1,P2,P3 are the centers, r1,r2,r3 are the radii       
# Implementaton based on Wikipedia Trilateration article.                              
def trilaterate(P1,P2,P3,r1,r2,r3):                      
    temp1 = P2-P1                                        
    e_x = temp1/norm(temp1)                              
    temp2 = P3-P1                                        
    i = dot(e_x,temp2)                                   
    temp3 = temp2 - i*e_x                                
    e_y = temp3/norm(temp3)                              
    e_z = cross(e_x,e_y)                                 
    d = norm(P2-P1)                                      
    j = dot(e_y,temp2)                                   
    x = (r1*r1 - r2*r2 + d*d) / (2*d)                    
    y = (r1*r1 - r3*r3 -2*i*x + i*i + j*j) / (2*j)       
    temp4 = r1*r1 - x*x - y*y                            
    if temp4<0:                                          
        raise Exception("The three spheres do not intersect!");
    z = sqrt(temp4)                                      
    p_12_a = P1 + x*e_x + y*e_y + z*e_z                  
    p_12_b = P1 + x*e_x + y*e_y - z*e_z                  
    return p_12_a,p_12_b 

P1=numpy.array([-2.5466649, -1.2534076, 0.0001741])
P2=numpy.array([-2.6229969, 1.6419994, 0.0000651])
P3=numpy.array([-2.6972299, 2.8495214, 0.0003421])
r1=1.01
r2=3.91
r3=5.12
print(trilaterate(P1,P2,P3,r1,r2,r3))
```

Though since this code gives this error

```
raise Exception("The three spheres do not intersect!");

Exception: The three spheres do not intersect!
```

I think there is an issue with your distances which would lead to there being no common point of intersection.

Edit : Editing the code as there was no imports

Comment: This is working when I change the distance to five decimal places! Thank you so much!
r1=1.01000
r2=3.90623
r3=5.11527

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept if you think this works for ur question. Trying to get some rep for my account :)